# How pass function pointer by call C# method via COM interfaces

Tags: c#, c++, reflection, com, c++-cli

I have this CLI c++ code for call method WpfApplication1.NetLauncher.Launch(IntPtr cb)
via reflection:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Reflection;

typedef int (__stdcall *PMyBeep)(); 

int __stdcall MyBeep()
{
return 123;
}

[STAThreadAttribute]
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

Assembly^ asmbl = Assembly::Load("WpfDemo");
    Type^ type = asmbl->GetType("WpfApplication1.NetLauncher");
Object^ obj = asmbl->CreateInstance("WpfApplication1.NetLauncher");
    MethodInfo^ method = type->GetMethod("Launch");

IntPtr pp=(IntPtr)MyBeep;

   Object^ magicValue = method->Invoke(obj, gcnew array<Object^>(1){pp});


    return 0;
}
```

And c# code:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
public class NetLauncher
{
    delegate int Mydelegate();

    [System.STAThreadAttribute()]

    public int Launch( IntPtr dwData)
    //public int Launch(string path)
    {



        Mydelegate codeToRun = null;
        codeToRun = (Mydelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(dwData,     typeof(Mydelegate));


        int res = codeToRun.Invoke();

      // ....
    }
  }
}
```

Now I try to call this method from Win32 C++ via COM interfaces:

```
    //   ....

    CComPtr<IDispatch> disp = launcher.pdispVal;
DISPID dispid;
OLECHAR FAR* methodName = L"Launch";
hr = disp->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, &methodName, 1, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, &dispid);

    //   ?????  DWORD nData=(DWORD)MyBeep;
   //   ?????  CComVariant *func = new CComVariant(nData);


CComVariant FAR args[] = {*func};
DISPPARAMS noArgs = {args, NULL, 1, 0};

hr = disp->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &noArgs, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I think I have to save function pointer (MyBeep) as CComVariant  in DISPPARAMS, but I don't know how???

Comment: can't you just use void* pointer since your managed code takes IntPtr anyway?

Comment: do you mind this: CComVariant *func = new CComVariant((void*)MyBeep); ??? It doesn't work :(

Comment: Neither void* nor IntPtr are COM Automation compatible types.  Calling functions through an opaque pointer is pretty fundamentally unsafe and unportable.  You can cast the problem away but you shouldn't be writing code like this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in front of my Windows machine... Can you try it for me?

```
DISPPARAMS dispparams; 
memset(&dispparams, 0, sizeof dispparams);
dispparams.cNamedArgs = 0;
dispparams.cArgs = 1;
dispparams.rgvarg = new VARIANTARG[dispparams.cArgs];
dispparams.rgvarg[0].vt =  VT_I4;
dispparams.rgvarg[0].iVal =   reinterpret_cast<int>(MyBeep);
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work:   Microsoft C++ exception: EEResourceException at memory location 0x0019e678..